# JavaScript variables getting lost in parent class

Tags: javascript

This is the parent class, Vehicle:

```
var Vehicle = (function() {
    function Vehicle(year, make, model){
        this.year = year;
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
    }

    Vehicle.prototype.getInfo = function(){
        return this.year + " " + this.make + " " + this.model;
    }

    Vehicle.prototype.startEngine = function(){
        return "Vroom!";
    }

    return Vehicle;
});
```

And the child class Car, which inherits Vehicle:

```
var Car = (function (parent){
    Car.prototype = new Vehicle();
    Car.prototype.constructor = Car;

    function Car(year, make, model){
        parent.call(this, year, make, model);
        this.wheelQuantity = 4;
    }

    Car.prototype.getInfo = function(){
        return "Vehicle Type: Car " + parent.prototype.getInfo.call(this);
    };

    return Car;
})(Vehicle);
```

What's happening is when I call

```
var car  = new Car(2012, 'Toyota', 'Rav 4');
```

car is always coming back as undefined. Any ideas as to why this is? This is code straight out of Microsoft's Programming in HTML5 with JS and CSS3.

Comment: Why do you have an IIFE in `Car`'s definition?

Comment: To inherit from Vehicle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `})();` after `Vehicle`, because `Vehicle` variable is `undefined` if you don't call your [Self-Executing Anonymous Functions](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/)

```js
var Vehicle = (function() {
    function Vehicle(year, make, model){
        this.year = year;
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
    }

    Vehicle.prototype.getInfo = function(){
        return this.year + " " + this.make + " " + this.model;
    }

    Vehicle.prototype.startEngine = function(){
        return "Vroom!";
    }

    return Vehicle;
})();

var Car = (function (parent){
    Car.prototype = new parent();
    Car.prototype.constructor = Car;

    function Car(year, make, model){
        parent.call(this, year, make, model);
        this.wheelQuantity = 4;
    }

    Car.prototype.getInfo = function(){
        return "Vehicle Type: Car " + parent.prototype.getInfo.call(this);
    };

    return Car;
})(Vehicle);

var car  = new Car(2012, 'Toyota', 'Rav 4');
console.log(car);
```

also in `Car` use `parent` instead of global `Vehicle`, like so

```
Car.prototype = new parent();
```